Complexification of a vector space $V$
The tensor product $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is formed by taking the real vector space $V$ (where $\dim V=n$) and extending its scalars from $ \mathbb{R} $ to $ \mathbb{C} $. Elements in $ V \otimes \mathbb{C} $ can be written as finite sums of the form $ \sum_{k} v_k \otimes c_k $ where $ v_k \in V $ and $ c_k \in \mathbb{C} $. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. For an element $ \sum_{k} v_k \otimes c_k \in V \otimes \mathbb{C} $, scalar multiplication by $ \lambda $ is given by:
$$\lambda \cdot \left( \sum_{k} v_k \otimes c_k \right) = \sum_{k} v_k \otimes (\lambda c_k)\tag1$$

Question 1: So, before we define the complex multiplication isn't we consider $V\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb C$ as a real vector space? Then for any $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, what is $\lambda\cdot\left( \sum_{k} v_k \otimes c_k \right)$? And what about its $\mathbb R$-basis and $\mathbb C$-basis? Like if I consider $\{b_k\otimes 1,b_k\otimes i\}$ where $\{b_k\}\in\mathcal B(V)$ basis of $V$, is it $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$-basis? Because from here it suggests that $\{b_1\otimes 1,\cdots,b_n\otimes 1\}$ is the $\mathbb C$-basis. Then I couldn't understand what $\{b_1\otimes i,\cdots,b_n\otimes i\}$ represent in $V^\mathbb{C}$? Does we forget what $i$ stand for in $\mathbb R$-basis $\{b_k\otimes 1,b_k\otimes i\}$?

Consider $ u = \sum_{k} v_k \otimes c_k $ and $ v = \sum_{j} w_j \otimes d_j $, where $ v_k, w_j \in V $ and $ c_k, d_j \in \mathbb{C} $. For $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{C}$,
\begin{align*}
(\lambda + \mu) \cdot u&=(\lambda + \mu) \cdot \left( \sum_{k} v_k \otimes c_k \right)\\
&= \sum_{k} v_k \otimes ((\lambda + \mu)c_k)\\
&=\sum_{k} v_k \otimes (\lambda c_k + \mu c_k)\\
&= \sum_{k} (v_k \otimes \lambda c_k + v_k \otimes \mu c_k)\\
&= \sum_{k} v_k \otimes \lambda c_k + \sum_{k} v_k \otimes \mu c_k\\
&= \lambda \cdot u + \mu \cdot u
\end{align*}
And,
\begin{align*}
\lambda \cdot (u + v) &= \lambda \cdot \left( \sum_{k} v_k \otimes c_k + \sum_{j} w_j \otimes d_j \right)\\
&= \sum_{k} \lambda (v_k \otimes c_k) + \sum_{j} \lambda (w_j \otimes d_j)\\
&= \sum_{k} v_k \otimes (\lambda c_k) + \sum_{j} w_j \otimes (\lambda d_j)\\
&= \lambda \cdot u + \lambda \cdot v
\end{align*}
Now consider the complexification as $V + iV$. Here, every element can be written uniquely as $ v + iw $ where $v, w \in V$. Let $ \lambda = a + bi \in \mathbb{C} $ with $ a, b \in \mathbb{R} $. For an element $ v + iw \in V + iV $:
$$
   \lambda \cdot (v + iw) = (a + bi)(v + iw) = (av - bw) + i(bv + aw)\tag2
   $$
Again,
\begin{align*}
    (\lambda + \mu) \cdot u &= (\lambda_1+i\lambda_2 + \mu_1+i\mu_2) \cdot (u_1 + iu_2)\\
    &= ((\lambda_1+\mu_1)+i(\lambda_2+\mu_2))\cdot(u_1 + iu_2)\\
    &= ((\lambda_1+\mu_1)u_1-(\lambda_2+\mu_2)u_2)+i((\lambda_2+\mu_2)u_1+(\lambda_1+\mu_1)u_2)\\
&= (\lambda_1 u_1-\lambda_2 u_2)+i(\lambda_2 u_1+\lambda_1 u_2)+(\mu_1 u_1-\mu_2 u_2)+i(\mu_2 u_1+\mu_1 u_2)\\
&= (\lambda_1+i\lambda_2)\cdot (u_1+i u_2)+(\mu_1 +i \mu_2)\cdot (u_1+i u_2)\\
&= \lambda\cdot u + \mu\cdot u
\end{align*}
And,
\begin{align*}
    \lambda \cdot (u + v) &= \lambda \cdot ((u_1 + iu_2) + (v_1 + iv_2))\\
    &= (\lambda_1+i \lambda_2) \cdot ((u_1 + v_1) + i(u_2 + v_2))\\
    &= \lambda_1(u_1+v_1) - \lambda_2(u_2 + v_2) + i (\lambda_2(u_1 + v_1)+\lambda_1(u_2 + v_2))\\
&= (\lambda_1 u_1 - \lambda_2 u_2) + i(\lambda_2u_1+\lambda_1u_2)+(\lambda_1 v_1 - \lambda_2 v_2) + i(\lambda_2v_1+\lambda_1v_2)\\
&= \lambda\cdot u + \lambda\cdot v
\end{align*}

Question 2: Again before we define the complex multiplication isn't we consider $V+iV$ as a real vector space? What about its $\mathbb R$-basis and $\mathbb C$-basis? Like if I consider $\{v_k,i v_k\}$ where $\{v_k\}\in\mathcal B(V)$ basis of $V$, is it $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$-basis?

It seems to me that in the first construction we extend our underlying field from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ as we define how complex scalar multiplication $(1)$ work here. But for the second construction it seems like we already had a complex structure over $V$. From here we can see how there exist an isomorphism $V\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb C\simeq V+i V$. But sill I could see how these two constructions do the same thing.

Why not try to show the following isomorphism: $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}^n$, for each element $e_i$ in the basis and $c\in \mathbb{C}$, $e_i\otimes c$ is mapped to $ ce_i \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Thank you for your comment @RHspqr Then what will be the $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$-basis for $\mathbb R^n\otimes\mathbb C$?

If you managed to show that $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes  \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}^n$ then you will notice that $e_i \otimes 1, i \leq n$ generate $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes  \mathbb{C} $ as a $\mathbb{C}$-space, by the isomorphism it is clear that these $n$ elements form a $\mathbb{C}$-basis.

For the $\mathbb{R}$-basis, just treat $\mathbb{C}$ as a real space then we can consider a basis of tensor product of vector space as usual.
